# sitefinity page setting for parameters

Tags: sitefinity

I have a controller that will be shared with three different pages in sitefinity. The API will take in different parameters for each of the three pages. Is there a page setting values I can set the parameters in and be able to use then in the Controller?

Comment: You talking like a rest api controller, or a widget?

Comment: ControllerToolboxItem, it in the SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add public properties to the controller and these will appear in the designer of the widget - when you "Edit" the widget in the backend you can set different values to these properties.

So, each of the 3 pages can set unique values there.

Example:

```
[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "TemporaryRedirectController", Title = "Temporary Redirect", SectionName = "Custom Widgets", CssClass = "sfMvcIcn")]
public class TemporaryRedirectController : Controller
{
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (SystemManager.IsDesignMode)
        {
            return Content($"This widget will 302 redirect to {RedirectUrl}");
        }

        if (!this.RedirectUrl.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return Redirect(this.RedirectUrl);
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

In the sample above, you can drag this widget to 3 different pages and when you edit it, you will be able to set a different value to the RedirectUrl field.

Comment: what about the views? Do I need to use the same view meaning can I use different cshtml files?

Comment: You can use any view you want.  I usually expose a public property called like "TemplateName" then pass that into the view return instead of a hardcoded string.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean create a public properties  `public string TemplateName { get; set; }` is that the name of the view? what would be return from the controller `return View(result);`

Comment: It would be: return View(TemplateName)

Comment: @veselin-vasilev what about the result data that is being return from the API call? Will that still be returned?

Comment: Would it be better to add a if condition in the cshtml? `@if (TemplateName== 'a')`

Comment: It's about readability and how complex the views are. For simple cases an if statement in the view would be fine. And yes, you can pass the model to the view, e.g. return View(TemplateName, your_model);

Comment: so would the TemplateName be something like `FolderName/index.cshtml`

Comment: Just the name of the view, e.g. Index. The index.cshtml needs to be inside the /mvc/views/controllername/ folder